# Moderate complexity between polynomial and exponential

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

There are ,,plenty'' of functions growing faster then any polynomial and at the same time growing slower than any exponential function (with base $>1$) e.g. $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x)=\log^{c} x$ where $c>1$ or $g(x)=x^c$ where $c \in (0,1)$. I would like to know some examples of problems for which there are (most efficient) algorithms which run in the time $f(n)$ for any such $f$. This question is motivated by the visible dichotomy between polynomial time algoritms and exponential time algoritms which one encounters in almost all classical problems.

Comment: Integer factorization can be done in sub-exponential time but is not known to be doable in polytime.

Answer (score 1):

The [Graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is an example of a problem unknown to be in $\text{P}$, that was conjectured to not be $\text{NP-Hard}$, and relatively recently (2015) Laszlo Babai published a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547) proving it can be done in $\exp(\log(n)^{O(1)})$ which is quasi-polynomial time.

Remark: Someone found a mistake in the paper, that was later fixed.